# nginx-rtmp + ffmpeg move mp4's moov to head on the fly

Tags: video, nginx, ffmpeg, mp4, rtmp

I have the following use case:

1) Alice publish stream to the nginx-rtmp server

2) The server convert the stream to mp4 (default is flv if I understand correctly, and a codec transformation is needed)

3) Bob should be able to do range request to that mp4 file while Alice is still publishing

However it seems ffmpeg command for converting a flv to mp4 can only be done when the mp4 file is fully generated, and then ffmpeg will do second pass and move "moov" to its new file's head

Our use case is to allow Bob use range request to retrive the mp4 file while Alice is still publishing (i.e. watch Alice's video as soon as possible) from time 0 (i.e. from the second Alice started publishing). Thus with mp4's moov at its head, it's simple to do range requests and implement the functionality. Raw RTMP doesn't seem to solve our problem, since we can't let Bob watch from time 0 of Alice's recording.

The question is:
1) Is it possible to do it while the flv is not fully generated yet?
2) Any other idea how shall we use nginx-rtmp/ffmpeg to achieve the functionality we desire?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible (unless you build a completely custom player, in which case why use MP4 at all). What you need is a streamable or fragmented format like HLS or CMAF.

Comment: Is there a way to "feed" the bytes of a h.264 frame or even some mpeg audio frame dynamically to a HTML5 browser decoder? Is that what Media Source Extensions (MSE) is about? Does it allow setting up the AVC Decoder Config & Audio Specific Config (PPS and SPS)? I can't see why an FLV containing only MPEG a/v data is not playable in browser (since its now basically a variation of mp4 format).

Comment: @VC.One Just tried out that flv DOES work in this scenario. i.e. I just need to point the http server to the flv recorded, and all the necessary requirements are met

Comment: FLV is certainly NOT a variation on MP4. MSE uses CMAF which is why I said that in my answer. (Or do you mean f4v. Because that is a variation on MP4, but that is just adobe trying to confuse you. Don't let them)